# Label.image shows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, label

I have been trying to use the following code for showing image on labels:

```py
for i in range (0, 10):
   img = Image.open("Toy Story.PNG")
   img.load()
   img = img.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
   img_title = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
   print(img_title)
   myLabel_image = Label(tab_recommend, height = 90, width = 90, image = img_title).place(x=108,y=200)
   myLabel_image.image = img_title #For creating reference
```

The last line is giving no attribute error and when I remove the last line, the image disappears.

Comment: if the answer was helpful and fixed the issue, mark it as accepted, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing last two lines to:

```
myLabel_image = Label(tab_recommend, height = 90, width = 90, image = img_title)
myLabel_image.place(x=108,y=200)
myLabel_image.image = img_title
```

`place` method does not return Label, but modifies it in-place, returning `None`.